# Babel not compiling global variable

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm missing the `var` declaration when coding. I have `preset-0` and `transform-runtime` installed. The console shows the following error:

```
key is not defined
```

This is the code I'm running:

```js
let set = new WeakSet();
key = {}; // missing var
set.add(key);
console.log(set.has(key));
```

But when I added the `var` keyword everything is fine:

```js
let set = new WeakSet();
var key = {}; // added var
set.add(key);
console.log(set.has(key));
```

The console outputs:

```
true
```

Which means I cannot create global variables at will with babel?

Answer (score 3):

Not like that you cannot.

You can always assign variables to the `window.MyKey = whateverValue` from any file and access this value from any other file in your app. But that's not the best way to share data globally in your app.

Best approach would be to create a file, say MyFile.js

```
class MyFile {
 constructor() {
   this.MyKey = 10;
 }
}

export default (new MyFile);
```

Now you can require this file anywhere in your app and access the same instance of MyFile. So,

randomFile.js

```
import MyFile from './MyFile'
MyFile.MyKey = 20;
```

This approach avoids polluting the global scope but you accomplish the same functionality.

Comment: But If I want a global object on intention, why Babel is refusing?

Comment: Because global object is bad practice.